# Using FFMPEG command to read the frame and show using the inshow function in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, ffplay

I am trying to get the frame using the ffmpeg command and show using the opencv function cv2.imshow(). This snippet gives the black and white image on the RTSP Stream link . Output is given below link [ output of FFmpeg link].
I have tried the ffplay command but it gives the direct image . i am not able to access the frame or apply the image processing.

[Output of FFMPEG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7abX.png)

```
import cv2
import subprocess as sp
command = [ 'C:/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe',
            '-i', 'rtsp://192.168.1.12/media/video2',
            '-f', 'image2pipe',
            '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
            '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-']


import numpy
pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout = sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)
while True:
    raw_image = pipe.stdout.read(420*360*3)
   # transform the byte read into a numpy array
    image =  numpy.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8')
    image = image.reshape((360,420,3))
    cv2.imshow('hello',image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    # throw away the data in the pipe's buffer.
    pipe.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: why do it like this? OpenCV's VideoCapture does the same. it can pass the rtsp link to ffmpeg and handle the pixel format conversions.

Comment: VideoCapture function takes approx 40% CPU consumption as my current task when i am trying to view the rtsp frame using ffplay command its takes only 0.5% CPU for single camera whereas if  cv2.VideoCapture function handle more than 70 camera it goes to 90% CPU . I need direct frame with less consumption of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a wrong output format, it should be `-f rawvideo`. This should fix your primary problem. Current `-f image2pipe` wraps the RGB data in an image format (donno what it is maybe BMP as `rawvideo` codec is being used?) thus not shown correctly.

Other tips:

- If your data is grayscale, use `-pix_fmt gray` and read `420*360` bytes at a time.
- Don't know the difference in speed, but I use `np.frombuffer` instead of `np.fromstring`
- `pipe.stdout.flush()` is a dangerous move IMO as the buffer may have a partial frame. Consider setting `bufsize` to be an exact integer multiple of framesize in bytes.
- If you are expecting processing to take much longer than input frame rate, you may want to reduce the output framerate `-r` to match the processing rate (to avoid extraneous data transfer from ffmpeg to python)

Comment: I have modified the necessary points but still it shows the horizontal lines in the frame .

Comment: IP camera vcodec is h264 by default and we are using the rawvideo . It can generate any problem. 
Correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: "IP camera vcodec is h264" Your screenshot indicates h265 (not that it matters)

Comment: So, studying your screenshot, the horizontal lines likely comes from all these dropped packets. Can you play the RTSP stream via ffplay w/out a hitch?

Comment: Also, if you have a capable GPU, you can turn on hardward decoding with `-hwaccel auto` input option

Comment: after using the **-hwaccel auto** command is return the frame is none .
Using the ffplay its working fine.

Comment: Suggest me any other way to reduce the CPU utilization . 
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Is this a CPU utilization issue or image decoding issue?

Comment: If you kill the subprocess immediately after the first read, do you see any warnings/errors from FFmpeg on your terminal? And does that image display correctly?

Comment: Yes i have seen the warnings and error after killing the process but frame is still not clear .