# Stream RAW8 video from camera using openCV and Python [Windows]

Tags: python, windows, opencv, video, ffmpeg

We have a camera that streams RAW8 video at 1920x1080. The GUID used is GREY. We are able to stream video from this camera using ffmpeg on Windows with the below command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -pix_fmt gray -video_size 1920x1080 -i video="CAM0" -f nut - | ffplay -
```

We are now trying to grab images from this camera using OpenCV using the below code snippet, but its unable to grab any frame (frame_grabbed is always false)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# reading the video from CAM0
source = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

height = 1920
width = 1080

source.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
source.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)


image = np.zeros([height, width, 3], np.uint8)

while True:
    # Extracting the frames
    frame_grabbed , image = source.read()

    if (frame_grabbed ):
        colour1 = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BayerRG2BGR)
        cv2.imshow("Demosaiced image", colour1)
    else:
        print("No images grabbed")

#Exit on q
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord("q"):
       break

# closing the window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
source.release()
```

Are we missing something here?

We then came across this post to pipe ffmpeg output to python ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71349914/using-ffmpeg-command-to-read-the-frame-and-show-using-the-inshow-function-in-ope)). However, when we are passing the command as below:

```
command = [ 'ffmpeg.exe',
            '-f', 'dshow',
            '-i', 'video="CAM0"',
            '-pix_fmt', 'gray',
            '-video_size','1920x1080'
            '-f', 'nut', '-']
```

its throwing

> Could not find video device with name ["CAM0"] among source devices
> of type video. video="CAM0": I/O error

I have verified that the camera is present using the below command:

```
command = [ 'ffmpeg.exe',
            '-list_devices', 'true',
            '-f', 'dshow',
            '-i', 'dummy']
```

This detects CAM0 as shown below:

```
ffmpeg version 5.0.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab 
--enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
[dshow @ 000001ea39e40600] "HP HD Camera" (video)
[dshow @ 000001ea39e40600]   Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_04f2&pid_b6bf&mi_00#6&1737142c&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 000001ea39e40600] "CAM0" (video)
[dshow @ 000001ea39e40600]   Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_0400&pid_0011&mi_00#7&1affbd5b&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
```

In short, we are able to capture video using ffmpeg commandline, but unable to grab any frame using OpenCV videocapture or ffmpeg in opencv. Any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you remove the double quotes on the device name?

Comment: Thanks @kesh. 
Device not detected error has gone now. 
Now I get: 

`Input #0, dshow, from 'video=CAM0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1756776.303854, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (GREY / 0x59455247), gray(tv, bt470bg/bt709/unknown), 1920x1080, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 10000k tbn`     


`[NULL @ 0000023db3705840] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'nut'
nut: Invalid argument`

Comment: The format, 'nut', was working while trying ffmpeg through the command line. What other output formats can we try for gray input?

Comment: A couple suggestions in my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why reading the frames using OpenCV is not working, but we may use FFmpeg CLI instead.

- Execute FFmpeg as sub-process, and set the output to `stdout` pipe.
- Read the raw video frames from `stdout` pipe, and convert each frame to 1920x1080 `uint8` NumPy array.

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import subprocess as sp

width = 1920
height = 1080

ffmpeg_command = ['ffmpeg',  # Make sure ffmpeg.exe is in the execution path
                  '-f', 'dshow',  # The input format is dshow (camera)
                  '-video_size', f'{width}x{height}',  # input resolution is 1920x1080
                  '-pixel_format', 'gray',  # input pixel format is gray
                  '-i', 'video=CAM0',  # May also try 'video="CAM0"'
                  '-f', 'rawvideo',  # The output format is rawvideo
                  '-pix_fmt', 'gray',  # The output pixel format is gray
                  'pipe:']  # Output the video to stdout pipe

# Open sub-process that gets in_stream as input and uses stdout as an output PIPE.
ffmpeg_process = sp.Popen(ffmpeg_command, stdout=sp.PIPE)

while True:
    # Read width*height bytes from stdout (1 frame)
    raw_frame = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(width*height)

    if len(raw_frame) != (width*height):
        print('Error reading frame!!!')  # Break the loop in case of an error (too few bytes were read).
        break

    # Convert the bytes read into a NumPy array, and reshape it to video frame dimensions
    frame = np.frombuffer(raw_frame, np.uint8).reshape((height, width))

    # Show the video frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

ffmpeg_process.stdout.close();  # Closing stdout pipe also terminates FFmpeg sub-process.
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `'rawvide'` as the output format. You may need to move all your camera options to the left of the `-i` argument.

You can try my [`ffmpegio` package](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio) if you need a quick and dirty way:

```py
import ffmpegio

show_log = True

# if you have to record for a fixed duration 
t_record = 5
fs,F = ffmpegio.video.read('video=CAM0',f_in='dshow',
                           'pix_fmt='gray', video_size_in='1920x1080', t=5,
                           show_log=show_log)

# if you need to stream input
with ffmpegio.open('video=CAM0','rv', f_in='dshow',
                   'pix_fmt_in='gray', video_size_in='1920x1080',
                   show_log=show_log) as cam:
    for frame in cam:
        # frame = np.array of shape (1x)1920x1080x1 (I think, reshape as needed)
```

If you need help on this, feel free to create a thread on the GitHub discussion board (not to clutter up here).

Comment: Thanks @kesh. I will try ffmpegio also!

By this "You may need to move all your camera options to the left of the -i argument." , did you mean like shown below: 

command = [ 'ffmpeg.exe',

            '-f', 'dshow',

            '-pix_fmt', 'gray',

            '-video_size','1920x1080'

            '-i', 'video=FX3_0', 

            '-f', 'rawvideo', '-']

This is giving me the below error though: 
[NULL @ 000002453bcd6400] Requested output format 'dshow' is not a suitable output format
video=FX3_0: Invalid argument

Comment: Then `gray` `pix_fmt` is not native to your camera. Move it to the right hand side.